# Problems with structure of a Gitflow Project

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a Web project with 5 modules : a front in Angular, a front in Symfony, a back in Angular, a new back in Symfony and an API in PHP/Symfony. This API is the center of these others modules.

Currently, I work on these 5 modules in the same time on many ways : hotfix (bugs), tickets, normal development, 2 big features.

I have decided to try to apply the git-flow structure on these modules and now I have these branches in API by example :

- master (connected to production)
- develop
- preprod (connected to test for clients)
- tickets
- feature1
- feature2
- hotfix (when I have bugs)

The problem is that all features or tickets need to be tested together but the client don't want to put all in production on the same time. Each time that I work on a feature, i need to merge it in the preprod branch to be tested. And when the client wants to put in production, I need to merge it in develop branch and after in master branch.

Moreover, it can be possible that the client wants a different action of the API on the same part of code when he uses the first front or the second. Then I have sometimes merge conflicts when I put in preprod.

If i have a bug, I do my correction on hotfix branch, I merge it on master and on develop and after I merge develop on preprod. It can be long to apply this correction to other features too...

Gitflow is it the best structure for my project ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get a great workflow for this?
I almost have the same issue. Lot of issues, but something I don't want to merge all my develop branch to release branch but only individual features.
And I don't really want to cherry-pick everything I need

Answer (score 0):

`git-flow` does not sound like what you would like to use with your given branch structure. `git flow` is very opinionated on the branching structure with using `master`, `develop`, `feature` and `hotfix` branches.

If you want to alter the structure of your branches, you could use the `develop` branch as the `git-flow master` branch, the `preprod` branch as the `git-flow develop` branch. You can use `hotfix` branches for both hotfixes and tickets. Then use `feature` branches for features. You can have multiple feature branches and hotfix branches at the same time (but note, this can cause difficult merges). You would still have to do manual merges from `develop` to `master`.

Comment: "The problem is that all features or tickets need to be tested together but the client don't want to put all in production on the same time."